# Android Studio 3.4.1 Layout preview render problem

Tags: android, android-studio, android-constraintlayout

I get "Render problem" error with the message "Failed to find the style corresponding to the id 2130969273" in the layout preview. It occurs when I use ConstraintLayout in my layout xml. Tried some techniques to fix

- Invalidate cache and Restart
- Rebuild
- Reinstall
- Change theme

but no result.

All dependencies are up to date. Build tools version is 28.0.3.

Answer (score 1):

Downgrade your build tools version to 27 also downgrade the version of support libraries to 27.Most of the times it helps to solve these types of issues.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well, with messages that said "Render problem" and "Enable new layout rendering engine". I solved this problem by enabling the `LayoutLib Native` plugin (if yours is already enabled, then try disabling it), and all the errors went away. See this answer on another question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64663563/14722177