# Render error in android studio layout editor

Tags: android, android-studio

I had a notification to enable the experimental Layout Rendering Engine. Since then I have layout rendering issues. I've searched for 2 days, nothing I can find. Any ideas?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What does your XML look like? According to the Studio source code, `RuntimeException("Aborting rendering")` is thrown after more than 50 xml were parsed to render single layout file (e.g. included and referenced resources). And stacktrace indicates kind of infinite recursion.

Comment: So something was wrong with plugins, the message popped up to sync my project, I did that and after a restart, all is working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Layout Rendering Engine" message is likely about layoutlib plugin in the Android Studio. There are two: layoutlib-native and layoutlib-standard. You can try switching them on or off (`Help | Find Action | "Plugins" | <enter>`). New rendering engine is about layoutlib-native.

[image: plugins dialog]